# How can I get output from "cmd.exe" in c# Windows without capturing it?

Tags: c#, windows

I have a simple xaml app for downloading and converting audio files. When I click download button i execute yt-dlp, get it's output and parse the file name from there to use it later. I achieved it using "RedirectStandardOuput" flag in process info. That means nothing gets printed in the cmd.exe window. Is there a way to leave the printing in the cmd.exe window AND save what was printed into a variable?

I googled it a lot but did not find anything that would allow me to do what I want (or maybe I just missed it). Here is my code for the execute command function:

```
private void StartProcess(string args)
{
    Process process = new Process();
    {
        process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = args,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true
        };
    }
    process.Start();
    string out = process.ReadToEnd();
    process.WaitForExit();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Console.Write(out);

Comment: It prints it into the c# console, not into the cmd.exe window that opens when the process starts.

Comment: CreateNoWindow = true

Comment: I want to have the window created and shown to user, i want its output printed in it but simultaneously i want to store that output in a variable.